# How to remove the duplicates from a multidimensional list with mutliple types in list

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv to try and detect movements on ships and track the movements of vessels. I am using background subtraction by creating a median background first and then comparing the frames to this. In my code currently, I am able to detect the contours and put these into a list. This list is then checked against any new contours and is able to detect whether it is the same contour as one in a previous frame. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to remove old contours from this list, meaning if any noise is detected, sometimes contours are given multiple ID's and as the list is ever growing, it is becoming laggy.

Below is my code:

```
    for c in contours:  # Looping over contours
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)  # Creating a bounding rectangle
        if cv2.contourArea(c) > 250 and w < 120 and h < 100 and w > 10 and h > 5:  # Checking if within the bounds that I want to test
            cx = int(x + w / 2)  # Gets the center point
            cy = int(y + h / 2)

            if len(matchedContours) == 0:  # Empty list
                objectNumber += 1  # Increase ID
                matchedContours.append([[x, y, w, h], [cx, cy], objectNumber, life])  # Adds the first contour to the list
                cv2.rectangle(differenceFrame, (x - 10, y - 10), (x + w + 10, y + h + 10), (255, 0, 0), 3)  # Generate rectangle
                cv2.putText(differenceFrame, str(objectNumber + 1), (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,
                            (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)  # Puts the text under the contour

            else:
                found = False  # Sets up necessary variables
                for i in range(len(matchedContours)):  # Loops over list
                    points, center, number, lifeLeft = matchedContours[i]  # Gets the values
                    oldcx, oldcy = center  # Gets the old center points
                    euclideanDistance = math.sqrt(float((cx - oldcx) ** 2) + float((cy - oldcy) ** 2))  # Euclidean distance calculation

                    if euclideanDistance <= 20:  # If the contour is within 20 pixels
                        matchedContours[i] = [[x, y, w, h], [cx, cy], number, life]  # Updates that item in the list
                        cv2.rectangle(differenceFrame, (x - 10, y - 10), (x + w + 10, y + h + 10), (255, 0, 0), 3)  # Generates a rectangle
                        cv2.putText(differenceFrame, str(matchedContours[i][2] + 1), (x, y + h),
                                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)  # Generates text
                        found = True  # Found the contour

                if not found:  # If not found the contour
                    objectNumber += 1  # Increase ID values
                    matchedContours.append([[x, y, w, h], [cx, cy], objectNumber, life])  # Updates list with new contour
                    cv2.rectangle(differenceFrame, (x - 10, y - 10), (x + w + 10, y + h + 10), (255, 0, 0), 3)  # Creates a rectangle
                    cv2.putText(differenceFrame, str(objectNumber + 1), (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,
                                (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)  # Generates text
```

Contours were generated using the findContours method from opencv.

matchedContours is a list that is created at the start of my code and is the list that is filling up. It holds the data for each contour.

life and lifeLeft was an attempt at trying to produce a solution where it would be removed after it was seen as useless 5 times in a row but this didn't work.

Comment: It is clear where you give new life to a matched contour, but where are you aging the unmatched contours and checking for expiration?

Comment: @RufusVS the aging code didn't seem to work out so I removed it, the life code doesn't do anything at the moment

Comment: Aging out unmatched contours seems the obvious approach.  Perhaps you should put back your aging code, and ask "Why is my aging code not working as expected?"